# React life cycles and Intersection observer

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, intersection-observer

I am building a image slider in React, based on CSS vertical snapping. There are 2 ways to interact with it, either throught scroll vertically or click the navigation buttons. I am using the Intersection Observer API in a React useEffect() to detect the active item. However, I can't seem to get it right without any useEffect lint errors. Whenever I include the functions in the dependecy array as suggested by the lint, the active item isn't set when scrolling.

Am I using a React anti pattern or am I just missing something?

[Live demo](https://jan-wagenaar.nl/v2/work/detail-cutwire)

Code:

```
const Slider = ({images}) => { 
  const [currentSlide, SetCurrentSlide] = React.useState(0);
  
  const setSlide = (id) => {
      SetCurrentSlide(id);
  };
  
  const moveToSlide = (id) => {
    if(id > -1 && id < images.length) {
      SetCurrentSlide(id);
    }
  } 

  return (
    <StyledSlider id="slider">
      <SliderWrapper items={images} setSlide={setSlide} currentSlide={currentSlide} />
      <SliderNav currentSlide={currentSlide} moveToSlide={moveToSlide} maxItems={images.length}/>
    </StyledSlider>
    )
}
    
const SliderWrapper = ({items, setSlide, currentSlide}) => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const { ref, inView, entry } = useInView({
    /* Optional options */
    threshold: 0,
  });
  
  const handleSetSlide = (id) => {
    setSlide(id);
  }; 
  
  const handleIntersection = (entries) => {
    const [entry] = entries;
    const activeSlide = Number(entry.target.dataset.slide);
    if (!entry.isIntersecting || activeSlide === "NaN") return;

    handleSetSlide(activeSlide);
  };
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      handleIntersection,
      {
        root: containerRef.current,
        threshold: 0.45
      }
    );
    Array.from(containerRef.current.children).forEach((item) => {
        observer.observe(item);
    });
    return function() {
       observer.disconnect();
    }
  }, [items]);
  
  return (
        <StyledSliderWrapper ref={containerRef} >
            {items.map((item, index) => {
                return <SliderItem key={index} index={index} image={item} isActive={currentSlide === index} />
                })}
        </StyledSliderWrapper>
  )
};

const SliderItem = ({index, image, isActive}) => {
    const imageContent = getImage(image.url);
    const imageRef = React.useRef()

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if(!isActive) return;

      imageRef.current.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center", inline: "center"});
    },[isActive]);

    return (
        <StyledSliderItem data-slide={index} ref={imageRef}>
            <GatsbyImage image={imageContent} alt={image.description} />
        </StyledSliderItem>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is the linter complaining about missing dependencies for `handleIntersection` and `handleSetSlide`? Can you create a [minimal, complete, and reproducible demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in a *running* codesandbox that we can inspect and debug live? Can you also clarify the error/warning more precisely?

Comment: I made a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/image-slider-rph46?file=/src/slider.js

And it is complain about missing dependencies of handleIntersection.

Comment: But if I add it, the active item is not set on scroll.

Comment: Does *this* [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-life-cycles-and-intersection-observer-m2kkl) work as you expect? It appears to do some snapping when scrolling horizontally, and the navigation buttons work.

Comment: It does! So using useCallback was the solution if I'm correctly?
Anyways thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've missing dependencies in the `useEffect` of `SliderWrapper`. You can simplify the code a bit as well.

SliderWrapper

Since nothing else calls `handleIntersection` callback other than the Observer you can safely move it ***into*** the `useEffect` callback body. This makes the only dependency the `setSlide` callback that's passed as a prop from the parent component.

```
const SliderWrapper = ({ items, setSlide, currentSlide }) => {
  const containerRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handleIntersection = (entries) => {
      const [entry] = entries;
      const activeSlide = Number(entry.target.dataset.slide);
      if (!entry.isIntersecting || activeSlide === "NaN") return;

      setSlide(activeSlide);
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, {
      root: containerRef.current,
      threshold: 0.45
    });
    Array.from(containerRef.current.children).forEach((item) => {
      observer.observe(item);
    });
    return function () {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, [setSlide]);

  return (
    <StyledSliderWrapper ref={containerRef}>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <SliderItem
          key={index}
          index={index}
          image={item}
          isActive={currentSlide === index}
        />
      ))}
    </StyledSliderWrapper>
  );
};
```

Slider

The other issue what that you were memoizing the `setSlide` prop in the child instead of the parent where it's being passed down. This caused the `setSlide` prop to be a ***new*** reference each render and re-memoized via `useCallback` in the child. React `useState` updater functions are stable however, so you can directly pass them to children.

```
const Slider = ({ images }) => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = React.useState(0);

  const moveToSlide = (id) => {
    setCurrentSlide(id);
  };

  return (
    <StyledSlider id="slider">
      <SliderWrapper
        items={images}
        setSlide={setCurrentSlide} // <-- pass directly to child
        currentSlide={currentSlide}
      />
      <SliderNav
        currentSlide={currentSlide}
        moveToSlide={moveToSlide}
        maxItems={images.length}
      />
    </StyledSlider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-life-cycles-and-intersection-observer]

If you wanted to remain with the `setSlide` handler in the parent, here is where you'd memoize the callback so the parent is providing a stable reference. Note that this is only useful if memoizing non-useState functions.

```
const setSlide = React.useCallback(
  (id) => {
    setCurrentSlide(id);
  },
  [setCurrentSlide]
);
```